# how to setup the assets folder in CodeIgniter like in Laravel

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

like the public folder given by laravel default i tried to create something like that for easy make up of my css, js, picture and so on. I tried configuring it like this. In my application/helpers/utility_helpers.php

```
    <?php
    function asset_url()
    {
  return base_url().'assets/';
    }
     ?>
```

I have my assests folder along with application, system, user_guide etc.
i confugured the autoload function of application/config as :

```
    $autoload['helper'] = array('url','utility');
```

when i hit any url in browser now, it says

```
    An Error Was Encountered

    Unable to load the requested file: helpers/utility_helper.php
```

how can i make it and can you explain me if i need to specify root for that helpers also.And if not can i simply access the assets like this:

```
    <img src="assets/base_components/build/banner.png">
```

in my view

Comment: You named you file as `utility_helpers.php` instead of `utility_helper.php`. Remove the `s` and it should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact the answer is very simple, you only need to put ../ before every file that is under **assets** folder, because the root of the codeigniter is in **application** folder, but how you can't put the **assets** folder there and for the best practices, let the structure of the project like below and apply this solution to the path of the files:

**Website Folder structure**
|---|application\
|-------(CodeIgniter application folders...)
|---|assets\
|-------css\
|-------images\
|-------js\
|-------robots.txt
|---|system
|-----(CodeIgniter system folder...)
|index.php

Path of the files
ex.:
CSS

```
<link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="../assets/css/plugins/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

IMAGES and others

```
<img src="../assets/images/build/banner.png">
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script src="../assets/js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>

<script src="../assets/js/plugins/jquery.scrollSpeed.js"></script>
```

**Note.:**
Always remember to applay the best practices to the code too (this will help for the performance of the the page too), like below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        meta tags
        favicons
        css files styles
    </head>
    <body>
        page structure code

        javascript files
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? It doesn't make sense... it's even not part of the problem. I don't reccommend to put `../` before every asset. CodeIgniter doesn't run with `/application` in the URL. Just use `base_url()` (or `assets_url()` if you want to do the same as the OP) before the asset's path.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks ok, it should work.
According to the error

```
Unable to load the requested file: helpers/utility_helper.php
```

there is no utility_helper.php file in application/helpers/ folder. Check if the file exists in that folder or if you don't have a typo in the file name.

Answer (score 1):

Yo can do this instead:

```
<img src="<?= base_url('assets/base_components/build/banner.png') ?>">
```